# Jquery Cycle - IE8 issues

Tags: jquery, css, cycle

I am having issues with Jquery and the cycle plugin in IE8.  As you can see I am getting a white background appearing when loading the page.  The cycle plugin itself seems to be working, but also seems to be the cause of this white background.  If I remove the call to cycle the page renders as I intend.

```
$('#welcome_slide').cycle({ 
                        fx:     'scrollHorz', 
                        speed:  1000, 
                        timeout: 0, 
                        next:   '#holeNext', 
                        prev:   '#holePrev',
                        after:   onAfter,
                    });


                    function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
                        $('#hole_slide').cycle({ 
                            fx:     'scrollHorz', 
                            speed:  1000, 
                            timeout: 0, 
                            next:   '#next1', 
                            prev:   '#prev1'
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: Did the cycle plugin come with some CSS? My bet is that you can modify the CSS to get rid of the white background.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma from `after:   onAfter,`

Comment: I removed it, but the white background is still there.